# Redirect multipe links using htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have shifted my website from one place to another. I have high traffic in the first place, so I need to redirect it on specific pages mapping to the second place. There are almost one thousand articles, so I need one thousand redirections. How to do that through `.htaccess`?

I am using the described below `.htaccess` code for this purpose but it is not working:

```
Redirect https://websiteOLD.example/article1 https://websiteNEW.example/article1

Redirect https://websiteOLD.example/article2 https://websiteNEW.example/article2

Redirect https://websiteOLD.example/article3 https://websiteNEW.example/article3

Redirect https://websiteOLD.example/article4 https://websiteNEW.example/article4

Redirect https://websiteOLD.example/article5 https://websiteNEW.example/article5

Redirect https://websiteOLD.example/article6 https://websiteNEW.example/article6
```

Whats wrong with the above described code lines? I have almost one thousand of such lines mapping each Wordpress article from old domain to the new domain.

Comment: `https://websiteOLD.com/article1 https://websiteNEW.com/article1` - you appear to have the same URL-path at the new domain? Is that the case? Are both the old and new domains pointing to the same place? Do you have control over this? Do you have access to the server config?

Comment: Just curious... where did you get your information regarding the use of the `Redirect` directive?

Comment: I copied the website from one place and pasted it to other place. So the domain name differs.

Comment: I am using cpanel, so I have access to the configuration of website for tools available in cpanel

Comment: @MrWhite from Google's help

Comment: _"Whats wrong with the above described code lines?"_ - apart from that Redirect is probably rather the wrong directive here to begin with (if the part after the old domain is the exact same on the new one, then you should use _pattern matching_, instead of writing a separate directive for each single one): It matches against the _path_ component of the URL only.

Answer (score 1):

> I copied the website from one place and pasted it to other place.

If you've simply migrated your site from one domain to another then you just need a single mod_rewrite rule at the top of the `.htaccess` file to 301 redirect all URLs from the old domain to the new.

For example, the following would need to go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` comment marker.

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect any request that is NOT for example.com to example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Where `example.com` is the "new" canonical hostname.

The `!` prefix on the above *CondPattern* negates the expression, so it is successful when the requested hostname does *not* match.

You do not need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` directive if this already occurs later in the file - it should already be part of the WordPress code block.

Test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and make sure you've cleared your browser cache before testing.

You need to use mod_rewrite (ie. `RewriteRule`) as opposed to a mod_alias `Redirect` (or `RedirectMatch`) directive because:

1. The `Redirect` (and `RedirectMatch`) directives do not match the requested hostname. They match the URL-path only. (Which is why your attempt is not doing anything.)
2. As a general rule, if you are already using mod_rewrite in other parts of the config file (ie. in the WordPress code block) then you should be using mod_rewrite throughout in order to avoid potential conflicts.

> Whats wrong with the above described code lines? I have almost one thousand of such lines mapping each Wordpress article from old domain to the new domain.

As mentioned above, the `Redirect` directive matches against the URL-path only. So, these directives will never match. See the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect).

The directive you are trying to use is also a 302 (temporary) redirect. This needs to be a 301 (permanent) redirect in order to preserve SEO. (But, as mentioned, it is a good idea to test with a 302 first.)

*Aside:* However, you should avoid using 1000+ individual directives/redirects in the main `.htaccess` file (when there is no discernible pattern from the old to new URLs). The issue is that these directives are processed (unnecessarily) on every single request. You need to prioritise your normal site visitors, not the "old" redirect. Ideally, you would perform such redirects in your application, once it has been determined that these URLs don't exist in the current site (a WordPress plugin is suitable for this). Although, there are techniques you can use in `.htaccess` to prevent all these directives being processed on every request (ie. only processed when the old domain is requested, otherwise they are *all* skipped).